# Transfer data from JSONStore between 2 MobileFirst applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to ask how to transfer data between 2 MobileFirst applications. Do Mobilefirst have any API for transfer data between 2 encrypted JSONStore?

Or

We have to use native codes for data transfer between apps method such as

IOS:App Extension or Inter-App Communication by URL

Android: Use Intent Share Action

Here is our scenario:
Client open AppA and tap on a button to get data from AppB. It prompt login of AppB(initialize JSONStore) and choose data from AppB then click OK to transfer data to AppA.

Do Mobilefirst have any API for transfer data to each other?

Answer (score 0):

To share data between applications you could use Simple Data Sharing.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing_terminology.html

You will need to review the doucment and adjust your applications accordingly in order to be able to utilize it.

Note though that I do not believe you can transfer JSONStore data as-is. You will need to take it out of the JSONStore, move it, and add it to the other JSONStore.